# SKSpriteNodes are Invisible after setting variable to another type

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

I'm writing a game where you have to dodge asteroids and other kinds of debris. So as for a test, I have made it so whenever I tap on the screen, it runs a command that changes the type of asteroids that spawn:

```
var s = Spawner()
didMoveToView(...) {
self.addChild(s)
}
***
***
TapMethod() {
s = NewSpawnerType() //NewSpawnerType is a subclass of Spawner
}
```

Spawner is an SKNode that has a function that creates new asteroids and randomly places them on screen.

Now for testing purposes, Spawners function is empty

```
func Spawn(RandomCordsX: CGFloat, RandomCordsY: CGFloat) {
}
```

And NewSpawnerType's function spawns in the asteroids:

```
func Spawn(RandomCordsX: CGFloat, RandomCordsY: CGFloat) {
  asteroid = Debris(xPosition: xCoord, yPosition: yCorrd, scale: 1, fileNamed: "asteroid",id: Int(xCoord))
    asteroid.texture?.filteringMode = .Nearest
    asteroid.zPosition = 1
    asteroid.hidden = false
    self.addChild(asteroid)
}
```

However, each time the screen is tapped, all the asteroids that spawn are invisible; they still collide with the player and result in a game over, but the asteroids are invisible. (node.hidden = true was not run)

How do I set the s variable to the NewSpawnerType() without it spawning invisible asteroids?

Comment: So you are postive that nodes are there (not off-screen) but invisible? Do you have visual physics representation enabled? Anyways, put a breakpoint and see if hidden property is really false and check alpha properties of those nodes.

Comment: I am not using visual physics. The Alpha of the Node and the Asteroids are both at 1.0 and the hidden property of node and asteroids both false. And another thing, The asteroids do show if s is set to NewSpawnerType before the game starts.

Answer (score 0):

> Maintaining the order of a node’s children can be a lot of work.
>   Instead, you can give each node an explicit height in the scene. You
>   do this by setting a node’s zPosition property. The z position is the
>   node’s height relative to its parent node, much as a node’s position
>   property represents its x and y position relative to parent’s
>   position. So you use the z position to place a node above or below the
>   parent’s position.
>
> When you take z positions into account, here is how the node tree is
>   rendered:
>
> Each node’s global z position is calculated. Nodes are drawn in order
>   from smallest z value to largest z value. If two nodes share the same
>   z value, ancestors are rendered first, and siblings are rendered in
>   child order.

When you have to do with the same zPosition , the order of your elements is based to the time when you `addChild` your elements to the parent node. You can have some problem when you work with animations so check the order of elements insertion and re-try.

To see other details look in the Apple official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html) (Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes)

Comment: I tried changing the zPosition to 99999 just to make sure, it didn't work. I think it has something to do with changing s to NewSpawnerType. Because if I run the program and s is NewSpawnerType all the asteroids will show

Comment: Have you try to change filtering mode to  asteroid.filteringMode = .Linear ? I know this options may cause some problems..